# Linux equivalent of Thread Director?

Tags: performance, scheduling, intel, multithreading

The 12th Generation Intel chips are rumoured to have "Efficient" and "Performance" cores. Apparently Microsoft's Thread Director, in Windows 11, takes advantage of them.

What will be the Linux equivalent? When can we expect it to be released?

Read about Thread Director here: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-intel-thread-director-marries-alder-lake-windows-11/

There is no way that I'm going back to Windoze. But I do want to use the latest hardware.

Comment: are you asking for Linux equivalent of rumoured hardware? ... wouldn't that be just another rumour?

Answer (score 0):

1. Thread Director is a feature of Intel CPUs, not Microsoft Windows'
2. Thread Director support still has to be implemented in the OS and currently only Windows 11 supposedly has it: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.15-Scheduler
3. Even without this support, Linux will **still work just fine** with Alder Lake CPUs, albeit not as efficiently as it could.
4. Intel hasn't yet announced when ADL CPUs get officially released, so it's possible that Linux 5.16 will support Thread Director. This kernel version will likely be released in December 2021 or January 2022.